# Rotation and Symmetries of Equilateral Triangle

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetry

Let $\Sigma=\{ 1,2,3 \}$ be the set of the vertices of an equilateral triangle.

[image]

Let $f=\sigma$ be the rotation of level with center of rotation $O$ over an angle of $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ radians or $120^{\circ}$

How can I find $\sigma(1),\sigma(2) \text{ and } \sigma(3)$? 
Also, is it a symmetry?

And what happens when the rotation is over an angle of $90^{\circ}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A,B,C$ the vertices 1,2,3 respectively. Since $\angle AOC=120^{\circ}$ you have that rotation by $120^{\circ}$ will send one vertex to the next one namely $\sigma(1)=2,\sigma(2)=3,\sigma(3)=1$
Since the result is exactly the same triangle by rearranging the vertices it is a symmetry of the equilateral triangle (it would be helpful to read a formal definition of symmetry).

When the rotation is $90^{\circ}$ you don't get a symmetry since you don't get the "exact same triangle" in some sense. A symmetry informally is an operation which leave the "shape" invariant;in this case the triangle, but might rearrange the vertices.

Rotation by $90^{\circ}$ will look like:

[image]

Comment: Ok..But..how will it be,after the rotation $90^{\circ}$ ?

Comment: @evinda I edited my answer

Comment: So,at this case,can't we find $\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\sigma(3)$ ? Is that the reason why it is not a symmetry?

Comment: It is not a symmetry because $\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\sigma(3)\not\in\{1,2,3 \}$. If you had their coordinates in the plane you can find the image of each vertex under any rotation.

Comment: I understand...Thank you very much!!!